# Why was Colin Creevey in the corridor the night he was petrified?

Tags: harry-potter

In the second Harry Potter movie, when Harry was in the hospital because of the Quidditch accident, it was nighttime, and he heard monster noises and it was going to get someone and then he talks to Dobby. Dobby then disappears and the teachers bring in the kid with the camera that got petrified.

**We know he got petrified only few minutes ago because of the voices. So why was Colin Creevey wandering the corridors late at night with a camera?**

Comment: But I thought this was explained pretty clearly in the boo-... Oh, movie-verse. Right.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> 'There was a bunch of grapes next to him,' said Professor McGonagall. 'We think he was trying to sneak up here to visit Potter.'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets* - p.135 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 10, *The Rogue Bludger*

Colin Creevey takes his camera everywhere, he's enthralled with the magical world. Ah man, a shame he didn't live to see Instagram. He's that kind of a guy.

Comment: also that doesn't explain why at night

Comment: if you were harry potter would you want someone to sneak into your room at night to give you grapes

Comment: You're welcome. I type my quotes out of the books because copyright and I occasionally make typos because, hey, you've gotta get in quick. I don't think it's that unusual for him to sneak up to visit someone at night when he was prevented from getting a good look and a picture during the day

Comment: @sluger Harry didn't want Colin to do *any* of the things that he did, but that never stopped him. What Harry wants is completely irrelevant.

Comment: If I was Voldemort, I wouldn't want Harry to try to kill me. How silly of Voldemort, wanting Harry to kill him.

Comment: @immibis: just goes to show - you're not Voldemort. So that's one more suspect off my list... :-)

Comment: "Ah man, a shame he didn't live to see Instagram." When did he die, i don't remember?

Comment: @Adrian Mann: In the final battle at Hogwarts, at the end of _Deathly Hallows_. He had come back into the castle although he wasn’t of age.

Comment: Even if Colin wasn't trying to bring grapes to Harry, I wouldn't be surprised to find Colin there.  He's an enthusiastic budding photojournalist, so Colin could have been there just to investigate the source of the monster noises and try to capture it on film (or whatever is magical equivalent of film).

Answer (score 17):

Colin Creevey was trying to sneak into Harry's room to give him some grapes.

> ‘There was a bunch of grapes next to him,’ said Professor McGonagall.
> ‘We think he was trying to sneak up here to visit Potter.’
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets: Chapter 10 - The Rogue Bludger</sup></sub>

He was trying to sneak into the room *at night* because Madam Pomfrey had declared that he (Harry) should have no more visitors. Presumably she'd refused Colin entry earlier in the day.

> They had brought cakes, sweets and bottles of pumpkin juice; they
> gathered around Harry’s bed and were just getting started on what
> promised to be a good party when **Madam Pomfrey came storming over,
> shouting, ‘This boy needs rest, he’s got thirty-three bones to regrow!
> Out! OUT!’**

As to why Colin had a camera with him, the simplest answer is that he's *always* got his camera on him. It would be weirder if he didn't have it.

Comment: Creevey, not Creevy :-)

Comment: @randal'thor - Weird. My ebook copy has it spelled Creevy throughout.

Comment: Weird indeed. Maybe JKR needs to sue her ebook publisher?

Comment: @randal'thor -  *"Dear JKR. The copy of your book that I ripped off from piratebay has a minor spelling error. Who should I complain to?"*

Comment: @Richard _“Dear Richard. I suggest you take this up directly with the Sirius Cybernetics Corporation, whose complaints department now covers all the major land masses of the first three planets in the Sirius Tau Star system. Best, Jo.”_

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - *Share and Enjoy.*